# Convert foreach loop to Linq expression

Tags: c#, linq

How do I convert following foreach loop into linq equivalent?
Also the foreach loop or linq performs better? The number of items here are only limited, may be in 100s. Thanks in advance.

```
ObservableCollection<ListItem> _ListItems = null;
string[] listItems = ListValueString.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (var lstItem in listItems)
{
    var itm = new ListItem();
    string[] listTexts = lstItem.Split(':');

    itm.ListText = listTexts[0];
    itm.ListId = Int32.Parse(listTexts[1]);
    itm.IsActive = true;

    if (_defaultString == Int32.Parse(listTexts[1]))
    {
        itm.IsInUse = true;
    }
    _ListItems.Add(itm);
}
```

Comment: Personally I wouldn't try to convert this foreach to a linq-expression, it will me very hard to read. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: A naming or type issue: `_defaultString == Int32.Parse(listTexts[1])`

Comment: For readability, please factor the main body of the existing for loop into its own function, such as `static ListItem Convert(string lstItem)` which can then be used in the LINQ `Select` as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query that uses an anonymous type to store intermediate results:

```
List<ListItem> items = ListValueString.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(lstItem => new { lstItem, listTexts = lstItem.Split(':') })
    .Select(x => new ListItem()
    {
        ListText = x.listTexts[0],
        ListId = Int32.Parse(x.listTexts[1]),
        IsActive = true,
        IsInUse = Int32.Parse(x.listTexts[1]) == _defaultString
    })
    .ToList();
var _ListItems = new ObservableCollection<ListItem>(items);
```

LINQ also uses loops so there will be no noticeable performance difference.